# How to fix contentResolver.openOutputStream(Uri) IllegalArgumentException: Media is read-only?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

### Update(rewrite) my question:

On Android 11 I get error(exception) shown bellow.
Attempting to save a file that is open in the "Recent" dialog box results in an error.
No errors if I selected the same file from sdk_phone_x86 > Download.
Difference in returned Uri:

```
Recent:
    content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A33
    filename: sample2.txt (size: 2894)

sdk_gphone_x86:
    content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Fsample2.txt
    filename: sample2.txt (size: 2894)
```

Android 10 (API 29) save files without any issues in both cases even Uri is different too:

```
API 29
Recent:
    content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/18
    filename: sample2.txt (size: 2859)

Android SDK Built for x86:
    content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Fsample2.txt
    filename: sample2.txt (size: 2859)
```

MainActivity.tk for reproduce issue:

https://gist.github.com/s3va/85c1c330f9786c60903934d7e3e8f479

### Original question:

I am trying to make a simple editor for small text files.
EditText view. Two buttons. "Load file" and "save file".
<s>With one only activity or with viewmodel,fragments and optionmenu.</s>

```
private var uri: Uri? = null

private val resultContracts=registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()){ u ->
    if(u==null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return@registerForActivityResult
    }
    uri=u
    contentResolver.openInputStream(u)?.bufferedReader()?.use {
        mEditTextView.setText(it.readText())
    }

    when (val p=checkUriPermission(uri,Binder.getCallingPid(),Binder.getCallingUid(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)) {
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Write Permission Granted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Write Permission Denied!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        else ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Down Know what is this permission: $p", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Whenever I open a file I get Toast: "Write Permission Granted.".
Is this the correct method to check if a record is available?
Files are always loaded in EditText (var or/and TextView) successfully.
Then I try to write the contents of the EditText to the same Uri. And sometimes get this exceptions:

```
2021-09-19 06:48:37.241 31926-31926/tk.kvakva.sevastexteditor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tk.kvakva.sevastexteditor, PID: 31926
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Media is read-only
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:153)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:704)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1818)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:1520)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:1496)
        at tk.kvakva.sevastexteditor.ui.open.OpenViewModel.savetext(OpenViewModel.kt:30)
        at tk.kvakva.sevastexteditor.ui.open.OpenFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(OpenFragment.kt:118)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:3122)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:3226)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:3126)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:3226)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentController.java:416)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:358)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:65)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:208)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:780)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1210)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3202)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

What is wrong with this code?

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.saveBtn).setOnClickListener {
    uri?.let { u ->
        contentResolver.openOutputStream(u)?.bufferedWriter()?.use { bufferedWriter ->
            bufferedWriter.write(mEditTextView.text.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

<s>I try to call it in the onCreate() in Activity.
In fragment from options menu.
In AndroidViewModel.</s>
Some times it works OK. Files were edited successfully.
Some times randomly got exceptions, when I click "Save" button.
I cannot find reason to leading to the error.
It is definitely not read-only media.
Files were actually found by they Uris when read and loaded in var and TextView and EditText.

<s>At last I got some regularity in behavior, when I copy file from my computer to android (emulator or real smartphone) errors is out and everything works as expected. Read, edit save text files in Download directory successfully.</s>

```
$ ../../Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb  push ~/qq.txt ./storage/emulated/0/Download
```

<s>Android is 11 on smartphone with this awful problem.
Emulator API 30 revision 10.
Not sure, but lower revisions not affected. Or I haven't caught them yet.</s>

Comment: `try to call it in the onCreate() in Activity. In fragment from options menu` If you try to save in onCreate then i wonder when you choosed and loaded the text.

Comment: `Read, edit save text files in Download directory successfully.` How did the user choose that file? Different?

Comment: It doesn't matter how. There are too many options. If you are interested in this problem, take a  look at the simplest: https://gist.github.com/s3va/85c1c330f9786c60903934d7e3e8f479

Comment: No. Nobody seems to care about this problem.